# CakePHP 3 - Using Google API Client

Tags: php, cakephp, google-api, cakephp-3.0, google-api-php-client

I have installed the Google PHP API Client library via composer;
https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client

The guzzle, psr, monolog, firebase and google directories have now been created in my vendor directory.

However, I'm struggling to add this as a dependency in my Controllers.

Most answers state that you need to create a Cake plugin in order to utilise new libraries in core but I'm struggling to find any resources explaining how to do this.

What is the correct way to use new libraries in Controllers that are not part of cake core?

Comment: You should be able to load any of the files using the `use` method. You do not have to create a plugin to use third party libraries.

Comment: Can you drop in the controller code that you are trying to use the google classes in?

Comment: How did you install the API in cakePHP ?!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should not have to do anything other than this:

```
 $client = new \Google_Client();
```

The autoloading should take care of it for you.

So, using your example:

```
<?php
  namespace App\Controller;

  class PagesController extends AppController
  {
      public function display() {
         $client = new \Google_Client();
      }
  }
```